# Encode cyrillic text with base64.encode

Tags: android, encryption, base64

I have a database which is encoded with Base64. I am getting data from that DB and i use it in my android layouts, also i send data to the DB. When there is Cyrillic text, it seems that it is not encrypting it properly, because i already fixed the decoding, but it cannot recognise the cyrillic encrypted text. I am using standard function to encode it is working properly with Latin characters:

```
public String encrypt(String text){
String result;

result = Base64.encodeToString( text.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP );

return result;}
```

I tried a few variations but nothing worked out. Do you know how to encrypt it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself:

```
String result = null;

    try {
        result = Base64.encodeToString( text.getBytes("Windows-1251"), Base64.NO_WRAP );
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks anyway :)